# get python Traceback in the powershell error handling

Tags: python, powershell, error-handling

I've a python call from a powershell terminal.

**minimalistic example:**

```
Try {
    & python "test.py"
    }
Catch {
    # Place individual error handling here
    $ErrorMessage = "$($_.Exception.Message)"
}

echo $ErrorMessage
```

**test.py** raises an error, example content can be:

```py
def make_sum():
    return a+b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_sum()
```

Why does the $ErrorMessage variable contain only the first line of python traceback?
`Traceback (most recent call last):`

I'd need complete call stack info as python provides:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/.../test.py", line 10, in <module>
    make_sum()
  File "d:/.../test.py", line 7, in make_sum 
    return a+b
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Any advice how to get a complete traceback into the string variable in powershell?

Thank you,
Honza

Comment: if the variables are defined before the scriptblock (`$PythonScript` `$ScriptParameters`), you have to pass them as remote variables. Also, any reason you're using `Invoke-Command` instead of executing it directly: `& python $PythonScript $ScriptParameters`, should work as well. If you want to redirect all streams to the success stream, using `*>&1`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: calling a script is not an issue here. As you write the `$PythonScript`, `$ScriptParameters` are defined above. And I can use `&` instead of `Invoke-Command` but it doesn't solve anything...  **I made a description more clear**